# SerialPort Read STX till ETX

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am new in c# development. I am using this code below from reading my serialport:

```
var mySerialPort = new SerialPort("Com3");
mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

mySerialPort.Open();
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new 
SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

 private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
     SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
     string tmp = sp.ReadLine();
 }
```

The problem is that tmp is always emmpty. Propably it tries to find a CR LF.
My serial port device which is conencted sends the line below:

```
STX(   0.000CRETX
```

Is there any option which i can change last character which tries readline to read?
So each time which reads ETX to return my string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are close, you just need to realize that the `DataReceived` event fires somewhat randomly.  It could fire in the middle of a message and you could only get half of the message.  So you'll have to build your own string and use the ETX character to signify you received the whole message.  Don't mess with the `NewLine` property, you don't need to when using `ReadExisting` per my example below.

```
char ETX = (char)3;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string currentLine = string.Empty;

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string Data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();

    foreach (char c in Data)
    {
        if (c == ETX)
        {
            sb.Append(c);

            currentLine = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            //parse CurrentLine here or print it to textbox
            //note you might have to invoke because this event is on its own thread
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, create your `DataReceived` event before opening the port.  It's not good to make changes to the configuration after you are using it.

```
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
mySerialPort.Open();
```

Comment: For me ETX = (char)3. I used part of this code and for my scale which returns ETX and this is what worked for me.

Comment: Whoops, you're correct.  ETX (End of Text) is (char)3.  End of Transmition (EOT) is (char)4.  I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine is fairly strict in how it behaves.

I tend to use this when reading from Arduino serial ports for instance:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
sp.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

You could also spin the reading off into its own thread that just read bytes until it has a full line before queuing that for handling by the main thread. Most likely overkill for your application.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend it, but you should be able to set it with this property.

[SerialPort.NewLine Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?view=netframework-4.8)

> Gets or sets the value used to interpret the end of a call to the [ReadLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readline?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_ReadLine) and [WriteLine(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_WriteLine_System_String_) methods.

Instead, it is better to read the byte array with `Read()` and check the data format as @omglolbah's answer.

Well that's your decision, so try it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

ReadLine is broken, as are other parts of the .NET SerialPort.
Please have a look at the links below for a correct implementation:

https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport#comment-9986
https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/reading-lines-serial-port

It basically comes down to this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[blockLimit];
Action kickoffRead = null;
kickoffRead = delegate {
port.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate (IAsyncResult ar) {
    try {
        int actualLength = port.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
        byte[] received = new byte[actualLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
        raiseAppSerialDataEvent(received);
    }
    catch (IOException exc) {
        handleAppSerialError(exc);
    }
    kickoffRead();
}, null);
};
kickoffRead();
```